# create symlink with ln but a loop will be created

Tags: symlink, ln

I would like to create a symlink from my source:

```
/nfs/www/example.com/sourcefolder
```

to this destination:

```
/var/www/example.com/destinationfolder
```

So I run this command:

```
ln -s /nfs/www/example.com/sourcefolder /var/www/example.com/destinationfolder
```

My problem:
If the command runs two times in the destination folder will be a loop

```
/var/www/example.com/destinationfolder/sourcefolder/......./sourcefolder
```

I tested also:

```
ln -s /dev/shm/ $APACHEHOME/tmp
```

So I will have a loopfolder "shm". The problem is, the webapplication need that the folder is named "tmp" but it should mapped to the memory.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use -v to have a more verbose output:

```
[root@centos7 ~]# mkdir /tmp/test/sourcefolder
[root@centos7 ~]# ls -l /tmp/test
total 0
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 6 Feb 21 11:40 sourcefolder
[root@centos7 ~]# ln -v -s /tmp/test/sourcefolder /tmp/test/destinationfolder
‘/tmp/test/destinationfolder’ -> ‘/tmp/test/sourcefolder’
[root@centos7 ~]# ls -l /tmp/test
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Feb 21 11:55 destinationfolder -> /tmp/test/sourcefolder
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  6 Feb 21 11:40 sourcefolder
```

The link loop is due to the behavior of ln

```
[root@centos7 ~]# ln -v -s /tmp/test/sourcefolder /tmp/test/destinationfolder
‘/tmp/test/destinationfolder/sourcefolder’ -> ‘/tmp/test/sourcefolder’
[root@centos7 ~]# ls -l /tmp/test
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Feb 21 11:55 destinationfolder -> /tmp/test/sourcefolder
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 25 Feb 21 11:57 sourcefolder
[root@centos7 ~]# ls -l /tmp/test/sourcefolder
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Feb 21 11:57 sourcefolder -> /tmp/test/sourcefolder
```

that tries to parse destinationfolder as a directory instead of a already existing symlink.

You can avoid this by using -T:

```
[root@centos7 ~]# ln -v -T -s /tmp/test/sourcefolder /tmp/test/destinationfolder
‘/tmp/test/destinationfolder’ -> ‘/tmp/test/sourcefolder’
[root@centos7 ~]# ln -v -T -s /tmp/test/sourcefolder /tmp/test/destinationfolder
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/tmp/test/destinationfolder’: File exists
```